# Can't align the table head and the table body in html, using angular with in-memory-data

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to align the table head with the table body.

This is for my project making a web-type student data-storing database.

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Id</th>
                    <th scope="col">NIM</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nama</th>
                    <th scope="col">Jenis Kelamin</th>
                    <th scope="col">Alamat</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nama Bapak</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nama Ibu</th>
                    <th scope="col">Jurusan</th>
                    <th scope="col">Prodi</th>
                    <th scope="col">IPK Terakhir</th>
                    <th scope="col">Hapus</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody *ngFor="let mhs of mhss">
                  <a routerLink="/detail/{{mhs.id}}">
                    <tr>
                          <td>{{mhs.id}}</td>
                          <td>{{mhs.nim}}</td>
                          <td>{{mhs.name}}</td>
                          <td>{{mhs.jk}}</td>
                          <td>{{mhs.alamat}}</td>
                          <td>{{mhs.nama_bapak}}</td>
                          <td>{{mhs.nama_ibu}}</td>
                          <td>{{mhs.jurusan}}</td>
                          <td>{{mhs.prodi}}</td>
                          <td>{{mhs.ipk}}</td>
                          <td><button class="delete" title="delete mhs"
                          (click)="delete(mhs)">HAPUS</button></td>
                    </tr>
                  </a>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

My image:

[image]

Comment: @AsiyaFatima - Please do not add deprecated tags to questions. Read the tag description. Also perform all the necessary edits together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is generating a new `<tbody>` for every item in your array. Add the `*ngfor` structural directive to your table rows (`<tr>`).

Comment: [link]https://imgur.com/a/8x8bZ0v
it did fix the alignment in the table body, but the head still off.

Comment: Could it be this? "The <td> scope attribute is not supported in HTML5. The scope attribute defines a way to associate header cells and data cells in a table. The scope attribute identifies whether a cell is a header for a column, row, or group of columns or rows." https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_scope.asp

Comment: Do you have any css applied other than bootstrap?